# Ordering categories in geom_dotplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data that looks like:

```
    sp sample_name  homo_anc     het homo_dev Heterozygozity
1   BF      RSFV1M 835314771 1857148  2106125      0.2212792
2   BF      RSFV1N 832516832 3049895  1576519      0.3643218
3   BF      RSFV1O 834367309 2651230  1762650      0.3160813
4   BF      RSFV1P 828847720 2902735  1604046      0.3483194
5   BF      RSFV1Q 835338722 2261941  1948946      0.2694231
```

...

```
21 WBM      RSFV1I 833924008 3378924  2285658      0.4024499
22 WBM      RSFV1J 833263882 3324019  2333676      0.3962252
23 WBM      RSFV1L 828667189 3354676  2266616      0.4021003
```

and am trying to plot as a geom_dotplot using:

```
p <- ggplot(het, aes(x=sp, y=Heterozygozity, fill=sp, colour=sp))+
     geom_dotplot(binaxis = "y", binwidth = 0.002, stackdir = "center", dotsize=7, binpositions="bygroup") +

  # Custom the theme:
  theme_bw() +
  theme( 
    legend.position="none",
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
    axis.title.x=element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.x=element_blank()
  )
```

but there's too much space between the two categories BF and WBM plus I need the order the show up in the x axis to be the same as in the data. I tried to add     `coord_fixed(ratio = 3)` but it just smashes the plot on the horizontal, and I tried to fix the order by doing `aes(x=sort(sp)...` but It only reorder the labels without moving the data points.

Comment: Could you make your problem reproducible by sharing a sample of your data so others can help (please do not use `str()`, `head()` or screenshot)? You can use the [`reprex`](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/magic-reprex.html) and [`datapasta`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/datapasta/vignettes/how-to-datapasta.html) packages to assist you with that. See also [Help me Help you](https://speakerdeck.com/jennybc/reprex-help-me-help-you?slide=5) & [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269)

Comment: Your data doesn't have the columns in `reorder(State, Crude.Rate)`.

Comment: 1) You cannot have `x = something` twice in the same function call. 2) Two themes gives an `Error: Cannot add ggproto objects together. Did you forget to add this object to a ggplot object?`

Comment: That was an error. Now the code is the way I run. Thanks